# Serverless Framework: How to properly define parallel branches?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I am trying to translate the following Amazon Step Functions definition from JSON to Serverless YML.
Here is the JSON version (which is working fine):

```
{
    "Comment": "Parallel Evaluation of multiple Book Pricing atributes.",
    "StartAt": "VerifyBookPricingAttributes",
    "States": {
     "VerifyBookPricingAttributes": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Next": "ReturnCombinedData",
      "Branches": [{
        "StartAt": "ConfirmBookAvailability",
        "States": {
         "ConfirmBookAvailability": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Comment": "This state will query DynamoDB table representing RS catalog. If the Book is found - availability will be confirmed",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookAvailability",
          "ResultPath": "$.BookAvailability",
          "End": true
         }
        }
       },
       {
        "StartAt": "ConfirmBookPriceIsValid",
        "States": {
         "ConfirmBookPriceIsValid": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Comment": "This state will query DynamoDB table representing Book Prices. If the input BookPrice matches the  Dynamo valid - the pricing will be confirmed",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookPriceIsValid",
          "ResultPath": "$.IsBookPriceValid",
          "End": true
         }
        }
       }
      ]
     },
     "ReturnCombinedData": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
       "comment": "Combining the result",
       "CombinedDetails": {
        "BookAvailability.$": "$[0].BookAvailability",
        "IsBookPriceValid.$": "$[1].IsBookPriceValid"
       }
      },
      "End": true
     }
    }
   }
```

The things to note are: Parallel type with Branches

I've started translating this into Serverless YML:

```
   stepFunctions:
      stateMachines:
        Process-BookPricingCreated-StateMachine:
          name: myStateMachine
          definition:
            StartAt: VerifyBookPricingAttributes
            States:
              VerifyBookPricingAttributes:
                Type: Parallel
                Next: ReturnCombinedData
                Branches:
                  StartAt: ConfirmBookAvailability
                  States:
                   ConfirmBookAvailability:
                    Type: Task
                    Resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookAvailability
                    ResultPath": $.BookAvailability
                    End: true
                  StartAt: ConfirmBookPriceIsValid
                  States:
                    ConfirmBookPriceIsValid:
                    Type: Task
                    Resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookPriceIsValid
                    ResultPath: $.IsBookPriceValid
                    End: true
```

I am running into an issue where Serverless complains about having StartAt and State as duplicate keys (since those are parallel branches.

How do I properly deal with the Parallel Branches using Serverless Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Branches should be a list and looks like you have an extra `"` in your first `ResultPath`

```yaml
   stepFunctions:
      stateMachines:
        Process-BookPricingCreated-StateMachine:
          name: myStateMachine
          definition:
            StartAt: VerifyBookPricingAttributes
            States:
              VerifyBookPricingAttributes:
                Type: Parallel
                Next: ReturnCombinedData
                Branches:
                  - StartAt: ConfirmBookAvailability
                    States:
                     ConfirmBookAvailability:
                      Type: Task
                      Resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookAvailability
                      ResultPath: $.BookAvailability
                      End: true
                  - StartAt: ConfirmBookPriceIsValid
                    States:
                      ConfirmBookPriceIsValid:
                      Type: Task
                      Resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:ConfirmBookPriceIsValid
                      ResultPath: $.IsBookPriceValid
                      End: true
```